# How to work with Google maps from Google app engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-maps

I have informations about some objects stored in BigTable(coordinates and few more) and I have to put this objects on Google map. How can I do that? (Please write some code example. I am  using java for my application).

Answer (score 3):

Working with Google Maps requires some background knowledge.  I suggest starting here: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/index.html. I would imagine that you'll use your server-side code to generate javascript from your objects in BigTable, which gets rendered in the client web pages and adds the markers to the map.